# How to handle pages with different orientation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am working on an app that has different device orientations depending on the page the user is in. I have no problem changing the device orientation when the user clicks a button to go to a certain page. My problem lies on AppBar's back button. I've made a small code example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 1 - Vertical'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Next page'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Page2()),
            );
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2 - Horizontal'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Back to Page 1'),
          onPressed: ()
          {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If the user presses the `ElevatedButton` on Page 2, I can change the device orientation back to `portraitUp` on `onPressed` function. However, if the user goes back using the AppBar's back button, the homepage won't be in the desired orientation (since `onPressed` wasn't called). What's the best way to make sure that the homepage stays in portrait mode, even if the user uses the AppBar's back button?

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

As  Krish Bhanushali comments states, this can be done using an `onPressed` as an async function. Here is the final code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 1 - Vertical'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Next page'),
          onPressed: () async {
            //Changes orientation heading to Page 2
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);

            await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Page2()),
            );
            //After exiting Page 2 sets the orientation back to portraitUp
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2 - Horizontal'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text('Back to Page 1'),
          onPressed: ()
          {
            Navigator.pop(context);
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What we can do is use the way flutter navigates. So what you can do is Set it to landscape before going to other page and use await at navigator(push) and later add the line to change back to portrait! Concept is As soon as your screen will pop we will be waiting for that be it any way from your button or appbar's!

Comment: @KrishBhanushali thanks for the reply! I'm not so sure how to add the await at navigator(push) since that part of the code is not async. Could you elaborate further? Thanks again!

Comment: `onPressed: () async {` you can add async like this.

Comment: It works now! Thanks! If you want to add it as an answer so you can get the reputation feel free to. I will update the post with the async function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works same as the concept of refreshing the page when we return. In brief we wait for the page to pop of from stack!

So what a good approach to tackle all the pops is:

```
  onPressed: () async {
            //We change to landscape before going to another page!
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight]);

            await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Page2()),
            );
            //We wait for the second screen to pop from anywhere
            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

          },
```

We can use alternate pathways like using state-management to tackle this but this is a simple way and works well.